# How to Display a different Text in a cell Grid

Tags: c#, telerik

I have a RadDataGridView (Telerik) with a column which half of the text has to be hidden. A number 123456789 has shown like *****6789. How do you do that?

```
    private void gvMyGrid_CellFormatting(object sender, CellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CellElement.ColumnInfo.Name == "colNumber")
        {
            if (e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells["colNumber"].Value != null)
            {
                string number = e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells["colNumber"].Value.ToString();
                number = new string('*', number.Length - 4) + number.Substring(number.Length - 4);
                e.CellElement.RowInfo.Cells["colNumber"].{DisplayText (or something)} = number;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I changed it in the view of SQL Server. That's the datasource of the grid.

Comment: (CASE WHEN LEN(Number) > 5 THEN '*****' + SUBSTRING(Number,5,4) ELSE '' END) as Number, {The length is always 0 or 9.}